# Sending activation emails when creating new customers in Shopify API

Tags: shopify

I want to be able to create an inactive customer in the API (/admin/customers.json) and have the "Customer Account Activation email template" sent to the new user. In the API docs (I'm using the the example for "Create a new customer with send_email_invite"), it refers to sending this option in the payload:

"send_email_invite": true

When I use this, the customer is sent an email based on the "Customer Account Welcome email template", which is what someone is supposed to get after they have already activated their account. How do I get the message with the activation link ("Customer Account Activation email template") sent instead? Thanks.

Comment: Or should I just create & send the password myself when I add the customer? I'd rather have them set their own password, but if it's not possible.